# App. name and bundle identifier change while uploading a new version - iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I have uploaded an app, using iTunes Connect.
The current version details are as follows:

```
App Name:- App1
Bundle Identifier :- com.aaa.app1
version: 1.0
```

The new version I will be uploading will have the following details:

```
App Name:- App2
Bundle Identifier :- com.aaa.app2
version: 2.0
```

I don't want to add a new app in iTunes Connect, but replace the current app with a new app name and a new bundle identifier.

I know, the older app users will have 1.0 and 2.0 on their devices, but that's ok.

The new users should have version 2.0 only, is this (app name and bundle identifier name) allowed while uploading a new version (2.0)?

Comment: Don't change bundle identifier. It is a unique identifier for your app.If you want to change bundle identifier you should create 'add new app' in itunes connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the Bundle Identifier, that is unique for every app. The app name can be changed in the .plist file.

Comment: I think, I will have to change the bundle display name while keeping the "bundle identifier" the same. So, while uploading the new version of the app. I will change the app. name in iTunes Connect and the "bundle display name" to App2. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Correct, you have to create a new version of the app and update the app name and NOT change the bundle id.

Comment: Hey, last thing. I will change the "bundle display name", will it be safe if also change the bundle name and executable name to "App2" .